# You're standing in a building & point to the glass window to refer to the space outside. Is it ok to say "There're more birds on this side"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

You are standing in a room on the 3rd floor in a building. You then point to the glass window to refer to the space on the left outside the building as showed in the picture.

[image]

And then you say "**There are more birds on this side**".

**Is it okay or natural to say that?**

Comment: Yes, but you use 'there are' in your question, and 'there're' in your title. There're is common in speech, at least in certain dialects, but you'll rarely see it written.

Comment: Yes, if you had previously been talking about the other side of the building!